# editing xml file node values and saving as XML string to upload to webservice in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have a basic XML file that contains the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rosters id_parent_provider="928" upload_key="8257QP01">
  <roster>
    <id_provider>928</id_provider>
    <provider_course_code>2022 - Medical Errors</provider_course_code>
    <id_course>895456</id_course>
    <id_publishing></id_publishing>
    <end_date></end_date>
    <attendees>
      <attendee>
        <licensee_profession>AAA</licensee_profession>
        <licensee_number>BBB123</licensee_number>
        <first_name></first_name>
        <last_name></last_name>
        <cebroker_state>CC</cebroker_state>
        <date_completed>DD-DD-DDDD</date_completed>
        <ce_credit_hours>E</ce_credit_hours>
      </attendee>
    </attendees>
  </roster>
</rosters>
```

I load the file in using:

```
$xml_string = file_get_contents($test_file);
$roster = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
```

and then roster contains the following upon var_dump:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["id_parent_provider"]=> string(3) "928" ["upload_key"]=> string(8) "8257QP01" } ["roster"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (6) { ["id_provider"]=> string(3) "928" ["provider_course_code"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (0) { } ["id_course"]=> string(6) "895456" ["id_publishing"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) { } ["end_date"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) { } ["attendees"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) { ["attendee"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (7) { ["licensee_profession"]=> string(3) "AAA" ["licensee_number"]=> string(7) "BBB1234" ["first_name"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (0) { } ["last_name"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (0) { } ["cebroker_state"]=> string(2) "CC" object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (0) { } ["date_completed"]=> string(10) "DD-DD-DDDD" ["ce_credit_hours"]=> string(1) "E" } } } }
```

I need to replace text AAA, BB1234, CC, DD-DD-DDDD and E with values I have stored in my website's database. How do I access the appropriate nodes and then change the value. I have tried following several simpleXMLElement tutorials, but not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there are more elegant ways to do this, but one quick way would be this:

```
$replacements = ["former AAA","former BB1234","former CC","former DD-DD-DDDD","former E"];

$attendees = $roster->xpath("//attendees");
foreach ($attendees as $attendee) {
    $lp = ($attendee->xpath('.//licensee_profession'));
    $lp[0][0]=$replacements[0];
    
    $ln = ($attendee->xpath('.//licensee_number'));
    $ln[0][0]=$replacements[1];
    
    $ce = ($attendee->xpath('.//cebroker_state'));
    $ce[0][0]=$replacements[2];
    
    $dc = ($attendee->xpath('.//date_completed'));
    $dc[0][0]=$replacements[3];
    
    $cch = ($attendee->xpath('.//ce_credit_hours'));
    $cch[0][0]=$replacements[4];
}

echo $roster->asXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<rosters id_parent_provider="928" upload_key="8257QP01">    
  <roster>    
    <id_provider>928</id_provider>    
    <provider_course_code>2022 - Medical Errors</provider_course_code>    
    <id_course>895456</id_course>    
    <id_publishing/>    
    <end_date/>    
    <attendees>    
      <attendee>    
        <licensee_profession>former AAA</licensee_profession>    
        <licensee_number>former BB1234</licensee_number>    
        <first_name/>    
        <last_name/>    
        <cebroker_state>former CC</cebroker_state>    
        <date_completed>former DD-DD-DDDD</date_completed>    
        <ce_credit_hours>former E</ce_credit_hours>    
      </attendee>    
    </attendees>    
  </roster>    
</rosters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using parameterized XSLT (special-purpose language designed to transform XML files) which PHP can pass into using the DOMDocument class to update needed node text values.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- DEFINE PARAMS -->
   <xsl:param name="lp_param"/>
   <xsl:param name="ln_param"/>
   <xsl:param name="cs_param"/>
   <xsl:param name="dc_param"/>
   <xsl:param name="ce_param"/>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- UPDATE NODES BY PARAM VALUE -->
    <xsl:template match="attendee">
        <xsl:copy>
          <licensee_profession><xsl:value-of select="$lp_param"/></licensee_profession>
          <licensee_number><xsl:value-of select="$ln_param"/></licensee_number>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="first_name|last_name"/>
          <cebroker_state><xsl:value-of select="$cs_param"/></cebroker_state>
          <date_completed><xsl:value-of select="$dc_param"/></date_completed>
          <ce_credit_hours><xsl:value-of select="$ce_param"/></ce_credit_hours>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```php
// LOAD XML
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load("input.xml");

// LOAD XSLT 
$xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');   
$xsl->load("xslt_script.xsl");

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// SET PARAMETER VALUES
$proc->setParameter('', 'lp_param', $licensee_profession);
$proc->setParameter('', 'ln_param', $licensee_number);
$proc->setParameter('', 'cs_param', $cebroker_state);
$proc->setParameter('', 'dc_param', $date_completed);
$proc->setParameter('', 'ce_param', $ce_credit_hours);

// TRANSFORM SOURCE
$new_xml = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);

// ECHO TO SCREEN
echo $new_xml->saveXML();

// SAVE TO FILE
file_put_contents("output.xml", $new_xml);
```